# Results of S3 function call are being cached by my Lambda function

Tags: amazon-s3, lambda, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I have a lambda function that uses S3.listObjects to return a directory listing. The listing is sometimes (not always!) out of date - it doesn't contain recently uploaded objects and has old modification dates for the objects that it does have.

When I run the identical code locally it always works fine.

Clearly some sort of caching but I don't understand where...

Here's the relevant code:

```
function listFiles() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        const params = {
            Bucket: "XXXXX",
            Prefix: "YYYYY"
        };
        s3.listObjects(params, function (err, data) {
            if (err) reject(err);
            else resolve(data.Contents);            
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: While eventual consistency does apply to object listings, long delays are not typical and there should be no caching from any other source.  Have you verified, via the bucket logs, that your function is actually making list-objects requests at the times the function is running?  The long delays suggest that you could have a bug in whatever is calling this function that causes results to be reused until the container is destroyed and the next invocation gets a new container.

Comment: To observe container lifecycles, define a global variable, e.g. `var container_id`. Then inside the handler, `container_id = container_id ? container_id : context.invokeid;` and `console.log('this container is ' + container_id);`  (context.invokeid has no real significance, it just happens to be a good source for a UUID.  We set this in the variable only if it is not set.  The variable is global, so it retains its value across invocations.  Locally, there's probably no reuse like this.) You should see the same ID for several minutes (assuming low traffic) and then it will eventually change.

Answer (score 0):

That is due to [Amazon S3 Data Consistency Model](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html). S3 provides read-after-write consistency for PUTs, however other requests - including listObjects are eventually consistent which means there could be a delay in propagation.

Comment: Thanks, but surely the delay is just a few seconds at most? I’m getting an out of date listing maybe 10 minutes later, sometimes half an hour.

Answer (score 0):

The read-after-write consistency in practice settles in a matter of seconds. It's not a guarantee, however. It's unlikely, but not impossible that amazon returns stale data minutes later, esp if across zones. It's more likely however that your client is caching a previous response for that same URL.

You might have run into a side effect of your lambda container being reused. This is explained at a high-level [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/). One consequence of container reuse is that background processes, temporary files, and global variable modifications are still around when your lambda is re-invoked. Another [article talking about how to guard](https://medium.com/tensult/aws-lambda-function-issues-with-global-variables-eb5785d4b876) for it.

If you are sending your logs to cloudwatch logs, you can confirm that a container is being reused if the logs for a lambda seem to be appended to the end of a previous log stream, instead of creating a new log stream.

When your lambda container gets reused, the global variables outside your handler function will be reused. For instance, if you change the loglevel of your logging calls to DEBUG at the end of your handler, if your container gets reused, it will start at the top of the handler in the same loglevel.

If you're using the default s3 client session (it seems like you are), then this connection stays in a global (singleton). If your s3 client connection is reused, it might pull the cached results of calls prior, and I would expect that connection to be reused in a later invocation.

One way to avoid this is to specify the If-None-Match request header. If the ETag of the object you're accessing doesn't match on the remote end, you'll get fresh data. You may set it to the last Etag you got (which you'd store in a global), or alternatively you may try setting a completely random value -- which should act as a cache buster. It doesn't look like `list_objects()` accepts an If-None-Match header, however. You may try to create a new client session just for the current invocation.

This  [article on recursive lambdas](https://theburningmonk.com/2017/08/write-recursive-aws-lambda-functions-the-right-way/) discusses the issue.